# echo inputs into programme when normal echo and pipe doesn't work

Tags: bash, pipe, echo

I am using this programme Vaspkit (https://vaspkit.com/installation.html) to generate some files for my research and have been using echo and pipe to pipe my inputs to perform operations in batches. While other "tasks" in Vaspkit can be run with echo and pipe, for example:
`echo -e "102\n2\n0.04\n"| vaspkit`

task 804 does not seem to accept any command further than `echo -e "804\n"| vaspkit`

Running a command `{ echo 804; echo 0.5; echo 3.2 20 ;} | vaspkit` will be stuck at the `echo 804` step and the terminal shows the screen waiting for you to input 0.5 etc.

While it's quite clear this is a bug in Vaspkit and I've emailed the developer to address it, I'd like to ask, out of curiosity, if there is any way we can still automatically input the commands into vaspkit's task 804 as it is now. I don't think `expect` will work because the prompts are not single line strings but some sort of GUI.

What I suspect is that unlike the other tasks, Vaspkit's task 804 gets input from terminal rather than standard input, hence the piping fails. However I don't know how to test that either.

For anyone interested to try, a set of input files for task 804 can be found in ./vaspkit.1.3.0/examples/MoS2_BP_heterostructure/. To test the `echo -e "102\n2\n0.04\n"| vaspkit` command, change one of the example input files for task 804 to POSCAR.

Comment: If stdin redirection does not work, I'm pretty sure that _vaspkit_ accesses the terminal device. At least I hope that they don't directly intercept the keyboard handler - this would be crazy and for me reason enough to dump that program.  You could use [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) or [expect](https://www.linuxcloudvps.com/blog/how-to-automate-shell-scripts-with-expect-command/). The former is simply a bunch of bash commands, while the latter requires you to learn Tcl.

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out, expect works. The pseudo GUI is made up of text symbols and expect can take in any input for the expect line. just had to key in the responses in the send line.

Here's the solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn vaspkit
expect " ------------>>"
send "804\n"
expect " ------------>>"
send "1\n"
expect " ------------>>"
send "3.2 20\n"

interact
```